# How to "CLEAR" a UIViewcontroller？(release)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Sorry but my English isn't very good, I'll try my best to explain my problem clearly.

didSelectRowAtIndexPath --> presentModalViewController --> Users finishing select values (didSelectRowAtIndexPath) --> dismissModalViewControllerAnimated -->

**(When finishing dismissModalViewController, there is still something been "memorized" in the viewController (EX. The rows selected by users))**

So I wish when the **second time** I call presentModalViewController, It's a "NEW" one **like when I first time call presentModalViewController.**

I got a UIViewcontroller connected to IBOutlet in a Xib.

DataController.h

```
IBOutlet CategoriesViewController *cateviewcontroller;
```

DataController.m

```
[self presentModalViewController:cateviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

I tried to point viewcontroller to nil.

```
categoriesviewcontroller = nil
```

but when next time I call

```
[self presentModalViewController:cateviewcontroller animated:YES];
```

categoriesviewcontroller is already nil, the app will crash.

I cannot use like

```
CategoriesViewController *vc = [[CategoiesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"xxx" bundle:nil];
```

because I didn't create a XIB file for this ViewController, This UIViewcontroller is under a XIB file

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options - either clear all choices on a viewcontroller when you finish using it

if you want to clear selected row on a table, you can do

```
[uitable deselectRowAtIndexPath:[uitable indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
```

or release it after each use, but that way you must recreate it every time you present it to the user, so it may not be in your master xib file.

Comment: Thanks for answering, 
I know I can do deselectRowAtIndexPath,
but there are some other things still can't clear very precisely.

Comment: And the second option, I've tried to release it after each use, 
but as you said, I must recreate it everytime before I present to user.

but the problem is, I can't create it. because it's in master xib file.

Comment: so the solution is to create a one more XIB file?

Comment: You don't have to use a separate xib, you may recreate it programatically, but using xib may be easier - that's what it is for.